# How do I make a JavaScript login form?

Tags: javascript

I have a regular HTML form with a text field, which is for a password. The idea is that every user logs in with the same password, therefore there is only one password for the site.

I'm trying to make some JavaScript to check this password, and if it's the correct password, redirect to another page, meaning that anyone who knew their way around basic JavaScript/had common sense could figure out the password by looking at the source code (it's weird I know).

It's really hard to find a tutorial for this, probably because nobody would want to create a password that anyone could easily find out.

Thanks in advance for your help. Also, I know the title is a bit misleading; I couldn't figure out how to describe it in less than three sentences.

Comment: what kind of check you are looking at? What is the code you have tried? and what is not happening? Please post some code you have tried and the issue you are facing.

Comment: `if(someInput.value === "secret") window.location = "http://...";` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are aware, that this is a huge security risk (i.e. no security at all), you could simply use the onsubmit handler of your form (if you have one), or the onclick event of an extra button. There, you would simply use

```
if (document.getElementById('myPasswordBox').value === 'P@55w0rd') window.location.href = 'the/new/url.html'
```

**UPDATE:**

To suppress submission of the form when using onsubmit, also add a `return false`. So:

```
<form onsubmit="if (document.getElementById('myPasswordBox').value === 'P@55w0rd') window.location.href = 'the/new/url.html'; return false">
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but when I submit the password, instead of redirecting to my page, it just redirects to /?myPasswordBox=P@55w0rd - and it's the same page as index.html

Comment: See my update, you need to suppress the actual form submit.

Answer (score 1):

Although makes little sense to me, you would want something like this?

```js
function check(){
  var pwd = document.querySelector('input[type="password"]').value
  if(pwd == "123456") window.location.href="https://google.com"
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Enter password</legend>
  <input type="password" />
  <button onclick="check();">Check</button>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="pword" id="pword">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#submit').on('click',myFunc);

    function myFunc(){
        $pword_val = $('#pword').val();
        if($pword_val === 'whateveryourmasterpwordis'){
            //do stuff
        }else{
            // do other stuff
        }
    }
</script>
```